# haskell State Monad put expressed using modify

Tags: haskell, state, monads

I need to express **put** of the *State Monad* with use of its **modify** function however I'm getting a 'Could not deduce' error on my following code:

```
class Monad m => MonadState m s | m -> s where
    get :: m s
    get = modify (\s -> s)

    put :: s -> m ()
    put = modify $ const ()

    modify :: (s -> s) -> m s
    modify f = undefined  --do { x <- get; put (f x) }
```

(*I did not yet define modify because my implementation in the comment beside it also returned a similar error but then on an expected return type *m s* instead of the actual return type *m ()*)

The exact error I'm getting is:

```
Could not deduce (MonadState m ()) arising from a use of 'modify'
from context (MonadState m s)
  bound by the class declaration for 'MonadState'
  at <..>
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (MonadState m ())
In the expression: modify
In the expression: modify $ const ()
In an equation for 'put': put = modify const ()
```

However I'm not sure what this error is trying to tell me and what I'm doing wrong here. If anyone could help me out it'd be much appreciated!

Best regards,
Skyfe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What `const ()` would do is transform the current state from whatever it is to `()`.  Since you want this to work on all states, this won't work since it means that it would be changing the state type from `s` to `()`.  It also wouldn't quite do what you want it to do.  You can use the `const` function, but it'd be better to write it without first.  I'd suggest making it pointful and using an explicit lambda:

```
put :: s -> m ()
put newState = modify (\currentState -> ???)
```

As a side note, your commented implementation of `modify` won't work, you'd really need

```
modify f = do
    x <- get
    let newX = f x
    put x
    return x
```

However, I would recommend leaving `modify` out of the class definition, as `mtl` does, since it's really more desirable to just implement `get` and `put`.  This helps you prevent circular definitions.

Comment: Thank you got the modify working now! As for the put function: I tried something like that first, like: put = modify (\s -> ()), but then I got the error that the return type should be m () while it actually was (). I figured the newstate should be converted to () for the return value of put, however I don't see how it can then return a m () value.

Comment: Why are you wanting to convert the state to `()`?  The state isn't changing type, it's changing value.  You have a new state, what should you be doing with it?  The only reason why `()` appears is because the monadic action has a result of `()`.  You can think of it as `put :: s -> State s a -> State s ()` instead of `put :: s -> State s a -> State () a`, you've got the `()` in the wrong place in your mental model.

Comment: Here I am trying to illustrate `put` not as a monadic function, but more of a "setter" for a `State` value.  The type signature of `s -> State s a -> State () a` wouldn't be used in actual code, it's only for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Aah I got it, got the (return) types and (to be set) values messed up in my head I suppose. So I basicly need to set the new state and return m (). So I figure I'd go something like: put s = modify (\s0 -> s) to set the new state, and then go from there to a m () return value?

Comment: I think I got it: put s = modify (\s0 -> s) >>= (\s1 -> return ()) - modify it to the state value to the new one, then bind the real value that lays within the state monad to be used to convert it to a new MonadState value (). Not sure if I done it correctly like this?

Comment: That would work, yes, although you could just do `do { modify (\_ -> s); return ()}`, but an explicit `>>=` doesn't hurt anything.  Keep in mind that this is a less general version of `void :: Functor f => f a -> f ()`.  Once GHC 7.10 comes out you'd even be able to use it without having to specify that your `MonadState` is also a `Functor` (even though it has to be mathematically).

Comment: Great! I think I understand it clearly now, thank you for your help and time, I appreciate that.